# Knockout and MVC - Binding to controls that were renderd using templated editors

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm just looking at Knockout JS and how I could integrate it with an MVC3 project I'm building.

Looking at the examples where data is brought down from the server, the knockout view model (KVM) is always populated by an Ajax call after the page has been rendered.

Is this the normal way of doing things?

My page currently renders controls using templated editor templates, eg:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Holiday.Destination, SelectListHelpers.ToSelectList(Model.HolidayModel.Destinations, Model.Holiday.Destination), new { @class = "optionselect", data_bind = "value: Destination" })
```

However, if using Knockout, shouldn't I be outputting the data that makes up the select list as an array within a script block and then using the knockout binding to fill the select list?

Thanks for any advice on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common and easy way to do this is to serialize your model values to the page. This would be something like:

```
var viewModel = {
  choices: ko.observableArray(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Options))),
  selectedChoices: ko.observableArray(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(SelectedOptions)))
};
```

Then, just use a standard data-bind on your select like:

data-bind="options: choices, selectedOptions: selectedChoices"

Comment: And I give up using the Strongly Typed helper (@Html.DropDownListFor) and use (@Html.DropDownList) instead? -

Comment: @BrightonDev - the MVC helpers are made for server side code. This is a fundamentally different paradigm. Having said that, there is nothing stopping you from creating your own strongly-typed helpers that render the controls with the appropriate Knockoutjs bindings. Personally, I'm not sure it's worth it because it takes you further from the metal but it is an option.

Comment: agree with the previous comment.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your advice on this.

Comment: @Steve - I'd like to use helpers to ensure that the control names match the server side view model property names to allow for easier model binding when the form is submitted to the server

Comment: @RP - I'm getting this error: "The argument passed when initializing an observable array must be an array, or null, or undefined". The Select List looks like <select id="Holiday_Destination" name="Holiday.Destination" class="optionselect" data_bind="value: Destination, options: Destinations">. ViewModel contains: Destinations: ko.observableArray(@(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Holiday.Destinations)))). The JSON that should be bound to the Destinations array looks like: {"Europe":"Europe incl Egypt, Turkey & Tunisia","ANZO":"Australia & New Zealand","WorldwideUSA":"Worldwide (incl USA & Canada)"}

Comment: @RP - Destinations is a dictionary.

Comment: I think that this should help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400387/knockoutjs-databind-to-a-dictionary-collection

Comment: Note that I needed to add the OptionsText and OptionsValue attributes for this to work.

<select data-bind="options: LocationChoices, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'id', selectedOptions: selectedLocation"></select>