# KnockoutJS - Databind to a dictionary collection

Tags: knockout.js

How do I use KnockoutJS to bind a dictionary collection to a select list.

If my "Destinations" dictionary looks like this in JSON:

```
{"Europe":"Europe incl Egypt, Turkey & Tunisia","ANZO":"Australia & New Zealand","WorldwideUSA":"Worldwide (incl USA & Canada)"}
```

How do I bind this to a select list. Something like this:

```
data_bind="value: Destination, options: Destinations.Value, optionsText: Destinations.Key"
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Typically, when dealing with a dictionary, you will want to map it to an array containing objects with key/value properties.

Would be something like:

```
function mapDictionaryToArray(dictionary) {
    var result = [];
    for (var key in dictionary) {
        if (dictionary.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            result.push({ key: key, value: dictionary[key] }); 
        }  
    }

    return result;
}
```

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/7yDTJ/

Comment: Ryan, How do we pre-select a value from the dictionary? In your fiddle I added value to selectedDestination: ko.observable("ANZO") and the second item is not pre-selected.

Comment: The example has `optionsValue: 'value'`, so it is expecting the value rather than the key.  I updated the sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/7yDTJ/

Comment: I'd look into the mapping plugin http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Answer (score 13):

I know this has already been answered but I thought I'd share a more comprehensive solution.

https://github.com/jamesfoster/knockout.observableDictionary

here's a jsfiddle which demos it

http://jsfiddle.net/HLnGs/

hopefully someone else will find this useful

Comment: This is really useful - I use it in my current university project and it works great. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

A simpler option if you're creating the server API is to just convert the dictionary to an array on the server and return the array:

```
Dictionary<string, string> myDict = ... ;
return myDict.toArray();  // returns KeyValuePair<string, string>[]
```

Now you can easily bind the array in knockout ...

```
<select class="form-control" 
  data-bind="options: opts, optionsText: 'Value', optionsValue: 'Key', optionsCaption: 'Show All', value: filter.myVal">
</select>
```