# KnockoutJS binding to Key/Value pair

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I am trying to bind to key/value pair data with KnockoutJS:

```
this.personal = {
  "name" : "Chuck",
  "country" : "USA"
};
```

In my HTML i use the $data binding:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: personal">

  <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>

</ul>
```

which results in:

```
[object Object]

[object Object]
```

Does anybody know how my binding should look like if I want to see this:

```
name: Chuck

country: USA
```

in other words...how I can show the property name and the property value?

EDIT: Someone pointed me at: https://github.com/jamesfoster/knockout.observableDictionary But I still hope to bind without an extra library

Comment: `foreach` is intended to work with arrays.  A good option is to map your object to an array that contains items with key/value props.  Take a look at this answer for a way to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400387/knockoutjs-databind-to-a-dictionary-collection

Answer (score 6):

There is an easier way of binding to a key-value pair using Knockout.js.  Say you have a key value pair that looks like the following

```
myItems: [
            { Name: 'Item 1', Value: 1},
            { Name: 'Item 3', Value: 3},
            { Name: 'Item 4', Value: 4}
        ],
```

Just use the following html to bind to the key value pair.

```
<select data-bind="options: myItems, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Value'></select>
```

References:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this:

```
<ul data-bind="keyvalue: properties">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: key"></span> :
        <span data-bind="text: value"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

For JavaScript:

```
function AppViewModel() {
    this.properties = { b: 'c', d: 'e' };
}

ko.bindingHandlers['keyvalue'] = {
    makeTemplateValueAccessor: function(valueAccessor) {
        return function() {
            var values = valueAccessor();
            var array = [];
            for (var key in values)
                array.push({key: key, value: values[key]});
            return array;
        };
    },
    'init': function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        return ko.bindingHandlers['foreach']['init'](element, ko.bindingHandlers['keyvalue'].makeTemplateValueAccessor(valueAccessor));
    },
    'update': function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        return ko.bindingHandlers['foreach']['update'](element, ko.bindingHandlers['keyvalue'].makeTemplateValueAccessor(valueAccessor), allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a function in your view model that converts the object property names and values into an array of objects with key and value properties containing the aforementioned name and value.

```
var ExampleViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.personal = {
        "name": "Loek",
        "country": "Netherlands"
    };

    self.personalList = function () {
        var list = [];

        for (var i in self.personal) if (self.personal.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            list.push({
                "key": i,
                "value": self.personal[i]
            });
        }

        return list;
    };
};
```

Your html template should look like the following:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: personalList()">
    <li data-bind="text: $data.key + ': ' + $data.value"></li>
</ul>
```

This results in the following output:

- name: Loek
- country: Netherlands

[Here's a fiddle with a working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/DemonGenius/wxLhocw9/3/)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should do

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: personal">
  <li data-bind=" text: country"></li>
  <li data-bind=" text: name"></li>
</ul>​

// This is a simple *viewmodel* - JavaScript that defines the data and behavior of your UI
function AppViewModel() {
    // Use an array here
    this.personal = [{
        "name": "Loek",
        "country": "Netherlands"
    }];
}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());​
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Aw5hx/

P.S. i never used knockoutJS before this post so i'm no world expert.

Comment: Hi Nicola,

thanks for your quick answer but that is not exactly what I am looking for. In my case I don't know the keys of the personal object. So I want to do a foreach over the personal object and show each Key (name) and Value. I hope you can help me further.

Comment: @LoekvandenOuweland if you don't know the keys / value in the personal object, why don't you iterate on those with a for cycle and then build the DOM dynamically before applying the bindings?