# KnockoutJS - Databind to a dictionary collection - with update

Tags: json, knockout.js

This this question here
[KnockoutJS - Databind to a dictionary collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400387/knockoutjs-databind-to-a-dictionary-collection)

I'm creating a drop down select from JSON coming from the server.
However at some point after creating it I wish to update the data.
I've created a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/LPrf3/

Which shows where I'm at at present.  I successfully update the select's observable array.
However... for some reason you need to click into the select from the drop down in order for it to refresh

Javascript:

```
$(function() {

var destinationsFromServer = {"Europe":"Europe incl Egypt, Turkey & Tunisia","ANZO":"Australia & New Zealand","WorldwideUSA":"Worldwide (incl USA & Canada)"};

var updatedDestinationsFromServer = {"Arctic":"Includes Polar bears and seals","Antarctic":"Just Penguins"};

function mapDictionaryToArray(dictionary) {
    var result = [];
    for (var key in dictionary) {
        if (dictionary.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            result.push({ key: key, value: dictionary[key] }); 
        }  
    }

    return result;
}

function  viewModel () {
    destinations= ko.observableArray(mapDictionaryToArray(destinationsFromServer));
    selectedDestination= ko.observable();
    updateDestinations = function()
    {
        destinations= ko.observableArray(mapDictionaryToArray(updatedDestinationsFromServer));
    };
};


ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());


});
```

HTML

```
<select data-bind="options: destinations, optionsText: 'key', optionsValue: 'value', value: selectedDestination"></select>

<hr />

<div data-bind="text: selectedDestination"></div>
<button data-bind="click:updateDestinations">UPDATE</button>
```

How can I get the select to update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reassinging `destinations` to a new `observabelArray` instead of updating the array. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/LPrf3/1/). When updating **any** observable, always pass the new value in as a parameter, never assign a new value with the `=` operatior.

Wrong Way:

```
updateDestinations = function(){
    destinations=ko.observableArray(mapDictionaryToArray(updatedDestinationsFromServer));
};
```

Right Way:

```
updateDestinations = function(){
    destinations(mapDictionaryToArray(updatedDestinationsFromServer));
};
```

Comment: It works... it finally works! :D

You know the annoying thing is I do already know that.
However it took me some time to find the map dictionary array solution and by that time my mind was turning to jelly after staring at the same thing for about 12 hours....
Much appreciated!