# Knockout array with dynamic key mapping to C# dictionary

Tags: javascript, c#, knockout.js

I'm trying to set a dynamic key to my knockout array to map to a c# dictionary.

```js
self.dictionary.push({ key: key, value: obj[key] });
```

This won't map to my dictionary as the server sees this as a key value pair. I had success using a Javascript object

```js
var obj = {};
obj[key] = value;
self.dictionary.push(obj);
```

but this hits the server as an object and won't map properly. I also tried using obj.entries here however, this is not IE compatible and will not work.

My dictionary is defined as

```
public Dictionary<string, short> dictionary { get; set; }
```

Any thoughts as to how to map this dictionary properly?

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400387/knockoutjs-databind-to-a-dictionary-collection

Comment: To start with, obj is already an object, self.dictionary.push({obj}); should be self.dictionary.push(obj);

Comment: Please add your `Dictionary` declaration in C#. e.g., is it `Dictionary<string, string>`?

Comment: Edit to include c# dictionary declaration

Comment: @Kendra, what do you use for deserialization? if it's `Newtonsoft.Json`, your second snippet should work correctly, see demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aUnqMi).